# Проблема со скрытием Navigation Bar

Tags: android, hide, navigationbar

Мне нужно скрыть панель Navigation Bar от пользователя, для этого в методе `onCreate` и так же в методе `onTouchEvent` я использовал простой код скрытия:

```
    decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions =View. SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Но моя проблема в том что, хоть при открытии он и скрыт, но при прикосновении 1 раз к экрану он появляется, после при 2 нажатии он опять скрывается. Как мне можно добиться результата что бы он вовсе не появлялся?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще это странный подход. Если навигационная панель не хардверная, то как юзер закроет приложение? Поясните, чего вы хотите добиться этим.

А попробовать можно вот это из [офиц. доков](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/visibility.html):

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener
    (new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
@Override
    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
    // Note that system bars will only be "visible" if none of the
    // LOW_PROFILE, HIDE_NAVIGATION, or FULLSCREEN flags are set.
    if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
        //системные панели открыты, их можно тут опять закрыть
    } else {
        //системные панели зарыты, их можно тут опять открыть
    }
}
```

});

В теории так можно предупредить появление нав. панели в момент, когда она хочет открыться.

Comment: я же говорю не для коммерческого пользования,это чисто для меня.

Comment: Не работает, точнее работает только в случае если бар навигации открылся полностью после он закрывает, но в случае полной работы программы даже через таймер оно то закроет, но у пользователя будет время что бы нажать на них(