# Скрыть Navigation Bar

Tags: android, activity

Задавал этот вопрос но для Статус бара, но теперь нужно скрыть Navigation Bar. Мне нужно скрыть `Navigation Bar` на андроиде, в том смысле что бы он вообще не появлялся, я сделал так что бы он скрывался, но при нажатии на экран он все равно вылазить и скрыть его программно можно только через 10 секунд после нажатия. Когда пытался как-то переопределять метод `onTouch` все равно не работает, нашел только один выход из ситуации поставить на метод `setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener` скрытие самого статус бара таймером через 10 секунд.

```
 public  void timer1(){
    CountDownTimer time_activity = new CountDownTimer(10000, 100) {
        public  void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility( View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility( View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);

        }
    }.start ();
}
```

Нужно сделать что бы он вообще не появлялся, как это можно сделать? Использую `Surface` для воспроизведения видео, может это как-то влияет на появления `Navigation Bar`? Уже задавал подобный вопрос [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/426603/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-navigation-bar).

Answer (score 3):

Вот так вам надо делать:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Comment: я понимаю,но когда прикоснутся к экрану все равно Navigation Bar вылазит.